# Localized Raw Resources from Android Expansion Files

Tags: android, localization, apk-expansion-files

we are currently developing an app that features different localized speech samples located in the different raw-subdirs in the res folder. (raw, raw-de, raw-es, raw-it.. and so on).

Due to this speech samples, the app size exceeds the 50 MB limit on the Google Play Store.

Now I'm about to integrate the Expansion File Handling. I'd like to keep the English base-speech samples in the base package and put all the other samples in the Main Expansion file.

Now my question:
I read all the documentation, but couldn't find a proper answer: If the expansion file is downloaded properly - will Android use the localized speech samples from within the expansion file automatically? Or will I have to load them manually dependent on the current locale?
I mean, all the Resource ID's would be existing, based on the English base samples. Maybe there is some possibility to add localized resources after the app launch to the resource system?

Comment: Let me understand... do you use **sampled speech**, instead of using the **TTS Engine**?! It sounds crazy to me.

Comment: Yes, sampled speech in all kind of languages. And please, no further Why-don't-you-use-this-or-that advices. I'm looking for a serious answer handling resources and expansion files together. Besides this will affect other non-speech-sample related assets too that are localized.

Comment: No joke. TTS is your best choice to output text. Seriously. What you are trying to do is really bad design.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint, but again, this is no option for me. The customer sent speech data of certain speakers and likes to have these included.